# Regex to split HTML by Tags which text contain less that n characters

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I want to split the following string by `<p>` tags which contain text less than 4 characters. Let's say `<p>1</p>`, `<p>2</p>` using Regex.

```html
<span id="_ctl0_contentMain__kDP_dp_Text" class="kDPText">
<p>1</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
<p>2</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
</span>
```

Comment: You sure you don’t want an HTML parser that will give you a nice list of elements?

Comment: No i am looking for javascript implementation.

Comment: There are HTML parsers for JavaScript. If you’re using a browser, one’s even built in.

Answer (score 2):

The following regex matches `<p>...</p>` with up to three characters between the tags:

```
<p>.{0,3}<\/p>
```

Demo:

```js
var input = `<span id="_ctl0_contentMain__kDP_dp_Text" class="kDPText">
<p>1</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
<p>2</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
</span>`;
console.log(input.split(/<p>.{0,3}<\/p>/));
```

Comment: I sincerely disagree, consider using your regex on [**`<p><p></p></p>`**](https://regex101.com/r/qkN2cr/1) where the matched part is nonsense. Really, use a parser instead.

Comment: @Jan I think you are right when you say the solution would resort to a parser. The example you gave, though it is not correct, to me as a P element would not contains a P elements by specs, if I'm not wrong
References: [p element has a phrasing content model](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) | 
[elements a p can contains](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resort to Regular Expression, you can resort to something similar to this code.

```
var string_to_split= document.getElementById("_ctl0_contentMain__kDP_dp_Text").innerHTML
var your_regExp = new RegExp("<p>.{0,3}<\/p>","ig");
var result = string_to_split.split(your_regExp).filter(function(x) {return x.trim().length;});
```

If you do not want to resort to RegEx you can use a script like this one (still vanilla javascript, but in older browser [i.e. ie8] you would use a polyfill for `querySelectorAll`, I guess ):

```
var allParagraph = document.querySelectorAll("#_ctl0_contentMain__kDP_dp_Text > p");
var split_para = Array.prototype.reduce.call(
    allParagraph,
    function(acc, x) { 
      if (x.innerHTML.length < 4) {
        acc.unshift([]);
      } else {
        acc[0].push(x);
      }
      return acc;
    },
    []
).reverse();
```

Sure, the first one solution is simpler but in the result variable there is a string, the split_para array has the original paragraph into an array grouped following your splitting specification